# Javers - Query for shadows by entity property

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, javers

In Javers is it possible to query for Shadows based on a property of an Entity? For instance I have the following class Employment

```
@Entity
public class Employment {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String designation;

    @ShallowReference
    @ManyToOne
    private Person person;

}
```

I want to find all employments belonging to a particular person using person id, is it possible to do this using Javers? I am trying to it this way because a user might delete an employment of a Person and I want to be able to retrieve the deleted employment record as well.

Comment: see this issue https://github.com/javers/javers/issues/556

Answer (score 0):

Employment looks more like a ValueObject than an independent Entity. Try to make it a ValueObject owned by Person. Then you would be able to find it using `byValueObjectId` queries (https://javers.org/documentation/jql-examples/#by-value-object-query)

Comment: I had the domain modeled like you said before but a bidirectional onetomany is a lot more efficient than a unidirectional one according to this blog post https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/